# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager with 2 different condition

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I want to display the layout of two different conditions using Recycler view and Grid Layout Manager.

First, when the device width is between 360 and 767,
and
Second, when the width of the device is greater than that.

The code below was used to allow the header and putter to occupy two cols.

```kotlin
        val mLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        mLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return when (adapter.getItem(position)) {
                    is HeaderItem, is FooterItem -> 2
                    else -> 1
                }
            }
        }
```

But I don't know how to arrange the internal items and set the margin according to the device size. (How to fix or maximize the size of the item.)

The example image is as follows.

[image]

(Is there a way to arrange only items in the middle, as shown in the example of width 1024, as above?)

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to do it. thx

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it.

I implemented it as follows using RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.

```kotlin
class ItemDecoration(context: Context, private val displayWidthPx: Int) :
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    private val horizontalMargin =
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.span_middle_margin)
    private val maxItemSize =
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_max_width)

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        val spanIndex = (view.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams).spanIndex

        outRect.run {
            if (parent.getChildViewHolder(view) is MyViewHolder) {
                when (displayWidthPx.pxToDp) {
                    in 1..767 -> Unit
                    else -> {
                        val displayStartEndMargin =
                            (displayWidthPx - (maxItemSize * 2) - (horizontalMargin * 2)) / 2
                        if (spanIndex % 2 == 0) {
                            right = horizontalMargin
                            left = displayStartEndMargin
                        } else {
                            left = horizontalMargin
                            right = displayStartEndMargin
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there's a better way, please let me know.

Thank you.